# htaccess REGEX to accept a particular set of characters in URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a particular set of characters that i want to mark as acceptable:

`a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`,`*`,`%`,`/`,`\`,`_`.

Now i am being able to create an .htaccess file that enables this for:

`a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`,`_`,

but the rest of the characters are not working. The url is giving a 404 error. here is the regex i am using

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

### UPDATE

**PS**- I have check many of the SO questions related to htaccess, but my problem is not solved. These were helpful, but whenever i try to add the remaining characters in the CHARACTER SET of my regex, its giving an 404 error.

Comment: This regular expression pattern will match if any character in the URL is alphanumeric or an underscore. Do *none* of [the plethora of StackOverflow questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+URL+regex) on the subject help you?

Comment: These were helpful, but whenever i try to add the remaining characters in the CHARACTER SET, its giving an error.

Comment: Did you escape the backslash and if applicable the forward slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

almost all characters lose their special meanings inside a character class, including `\` `*` and `/`

Try this: `[a-zA-Z0-9_\/%*]+`